# Comparison between a list and numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Well I am a newbie in python and i recently started with numpy intro. Starting with the comparison between numpy and list, numpy occupies less memory storage space. But after what i tried in the IDLE shell , I am confused.  Here's what I have done

```
list1=[1,2,3]

sys.getsizeof(list1)

48
a=np.array([1,2,3])

sys.getsizeof(a)

60
```

Why is the numpy array, I created occupying more size than the list object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `getsizeof` is not always the best way to compare the size of these two objects.  [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Only the memory consumption directly attributed to the object is accounted for, not the memory consumption of objects it refers to.

To answer your question however, what you're seeing here is simply the additional overhead of a `numpy` array, which will provide skewed results on such a small input sample.

If you want to know the size of the *just the data* contained in a `numpy` array, there is an attribute you can check:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a.nbytes
12
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=np.int8)
>>> a.nbytes
3
```

[This will not include the overhead](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.nbytes.html):

> Does not include memory consumed by non-element attributes of the array object.

Comment: Thanks,  Do you know of any good source from where I can learn numpy?